# Blocking disposing off object by GC due to callback

Tags: c#, callback, garbage-collection, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI application where I expose subscription API for our clients.
In this API, they give me a C# callback (Action) which I keep calling from my application to publish some data.

Problem is: clients say when their object is gone out of scope, GC is not called on their object because the callback they have given me is their member variable and my app have a strong reference to it, which is true, I store this callback in my app.

I understand this would be very common problem in this kind of scenario. But I am not sure how this problem can be resolved.
So I need advice:
How my app should handle this callback so that it doesn't block GC to dispose client object.

If more details are required, pls leave a comment.

Comment: Somebody is using a global variable inappropriately.  Could be you, could be the client app storing a reference to your object in a static variable.  If it is you then you have to do something about it, WeakReference can get that job done.  But with the considerable new risk that the client app is *expecting* you to keep his object alive in some cases, they usually do.  Cut that Gordian knot by allowing the client app to explicitly unregister the callback, now it is completely under their control.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Use [weak references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of your strong references.
- Give your users a chance to deregister the `Action` they registered with you.

Both should work.